# Can I implement methods of a QWebView from a ui?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qwebview

I use Qt designer to make an interface and I have an QWebView in it. I would like to reimplement the fonction `mouseDoubleClickEvent` of my QWebView.

Can I do that? I know I have to use `ui->webview` to access it, I know I can use the signals easily with `on_webView_selectionChanged` for example, but what about other methods like `mouseDoubleClickEvent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `mouseDoubleCLickEvent` is a virtual protected function, you will need to subclass `QWebView` and re-implement the method in your subclass. The documentation for `mouseDoubleClickEvent`, a method of `QWidget`, can be found [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwidget.html#mouseDoubleClickEvent). After this, you will probably want to integrate your custom widget with Qt Designer. I am not familiar with the program, but [this documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/designer-using-custom-widgets.html) might prove useful. (**Edit**: it appears that promoting a custom subclass of `QWebView` requires additional steps which are documented [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/34289-How-to-Promote-QWebview-%28Custom-widget%29) and [here](https://sites.google.com/a/embeddedlab.org/community/technical-articles/qt/qt-posts/howtopromoteaqwebviewclasstoacustomcomponent)) I do not know of any pure GUI method for creating the custom subclass you need.

Comment: It almost works...but I'm stuck because the final line doesn't work : Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(webviewcustomplugin, WebViewCustomPlugin);            it says :error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

Comment: Since you're only overriding one method, you probably want the simpler "class promotion" mechanism.

Comment: ok for the error above I was just stupid I forgot to include QtPlugin...I looked for that at first because I also thought that would be enough...but I couldn't make it works :S QWebView is not in the choices to promote....am I doing it wrong...for now I tried the other way but my plugin doesn't appears in QtDesigner...

Comment: I saw a video that explain well how to do it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt-YCxgEnyw) keep testing

Comment: I have simply made a subclass of 'QWebView' and re-implement 'mouseDoubleClickEvent' in it. Then I just had to promote my 'QWebView' of the ui as 'MyWebViewWidget'. Then I can do what I want in my custom webview, and simply use signal to get useful informations like selectedText! thanks a lot!